# I can't delete a post from my database using a button. React-Graphql

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, mern

Hey guys I'm trying to delete a post from my database but I'm having issues getting this button to work. I moved the whole function to my feed file, I created a different function and still doesn't work. I really appreciate your help.`

```js
…All the imports

function DeletePostBtn ({ postId }){
  const navigate = useNavigate;`
  const { _id } = useParams();`

  const [deletePost] = useMutation(REMOVE_POST, {
    variables: {id: _id },
    onCompleted: () => navigate('/'),
    refetchQueries: [{ query: QUERY_POSTS }],
  });
    
  // remove handler
  const removeHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      await deletePost({ variables: {_id} });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Button onClick={() => {
      removeHandler();
      alert('clicked');
    }}>
      <Trash/>
   </Button>  
  );
}

export default DeletePostBtn;
```

and I'm calling it in my Feed page`

```js
const Feed = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <div className="feed container gx-12">
      <div className="feedWrapper row">
        <AddPost />
        {posts &&
          posts.map((post) => (
            <Card key={post._id}>
              <Card.Header>
                <Row>
                  <Col xs={1}>
                    <div className="">
                      <Card.Img
                        src={Bot}
                        className="rounded-circle"
                        style={{ width: '50px' }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <Link
                      to={`/profile/${post.username}`}
                      style={{ fontWeight: 750 }}
                      className="text-start"
                    >
                      u/{post.username}
                    </Link>
                  </Col>
                  <Col className="text-end">
                    <Dropdown>
                      <Dropdown.Toggle
                        variant="text-dark"
                        id="dropdown-basic"
                        size="lg"
                        bsPrefix
                        className="dropdown"
                      >
                        <ThreeDots />
                      </Dropdown.Toggle>
                      <Dropdown.Menu>
                        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">
                          <Stack direction="horizontal">
                            <DeletePost />
                            DELETE
                          </Stack>
                        </Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">EDIT</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">PROFILE</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">
                          SUBCODEIT
                        </Dropdown.Item>
                      </Dropdown.Menu>
                    </Dropdown>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Card.Header>
              <Card.Title>{post.enteredTitle}</Card.Title>
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Text>{post.enteredText}</Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
              <Card.Footer className="cardFooter">
                <div>
                  Comments: {post.commentCount} || Click to{' '}
                  {post.commentCount ? 'Add' : 'Start'} comments.
                </div>
                <div>{post.createdAt}</div>
              </Card.Footer>
            </Card>
          ))}
        ;
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: How is `<DeletePost />` supposed to pass the post's `_id`?  `useParams` will get the route parameter but your `<DeletePost />` is inside a `.map()`. Shouldn't you use it with `<DeletePost postId={post._id} />`

Comment: yes, I did not notice that thank you, however, I'm still missing something the btn still broken

Answer (score 0):

Change your component to use the `postId` parameter instead of `useParams()`:

```
function DeletePostBtn ({ postId }){
  const navigate = useNavigate;`
  
  const [deletePost] = useMutation(REMOVE_POST, {
    variables: {id: postId },
    onCompleted: () => navigate('/'),
    refetchQueries: [{ query: QUERY_POSTS }],
  });
  …
}
```

Then pass the `postId` to the component in in your `.map()`:

```
<DeletePost postId={post._id}/>
```